# what is reference copying technique and why string object reference values is not changed?

Tags: java

**strong text**what is reference copying technique?

```
The reference copying technique is much more difficult to use for mutable objects, because if any user of a reference to a mutable object changes it, all other users of that reference will see the change
```

Another thing I tested sample code below for pass-by-value & pass-by-reference.The primitive values are pass-by-value and object reference are pass-by-reference.In the sample example,I tested types a string contant,String object,String buffer,int,ArrayList.

```
          String s="foo";
    String sample1=new String("dog");
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("abc");
    ArrayList l=new ArrayList();
    l.add("ssss");
    l.add("bbbb");
    l.add("ssbbbss");
    l.add("bbbb");
    l.add("bbbb");
    int k=14,listsize=0;
    listsize=l.size();
    TesingPrimitivRefernce.generateString(s);
    TesingPrimitivRefernce.generateString(sample1);
    TesingPrimitivRefernce.generateStringBuilder(sb);
    TesingPrimitivRefernce.generateInt(k);
    TesingPrimitivRefernce.generateNewList(l);
    System.out.println("String============"+s+" String Buffer========"+sb+" String object "+sample1);
    System.out.println("int Primitive Values==="+k);
    System.out.println("Orignal List Size"+listsize+" After called method List Size=========="+l.size());


 public static void generateString(String s){
       s=s.concat("d");
   }
   public static void generateStringBuilder(StringBuffer s){
       s=s.append("d");

   }
   public static void generateInt(int s){
       s=10;

   }
   public static void generateNewList(ArrayList list){
      list.remove("bbbb");

   }
```

**My doubt is why String object is not changed (**i.e.,variable sample1**) after calling ***TesingPrimitivRefernce.generateString(sample1).***but in the arraylist i removed the value "bbb" and automatically decrase size.Here I passed String object reference.So why it is not changed?**

Comment: String objects are _not_ mutable.

Comment: Read this. Everything in Java is pass by value. [Passing a String by reference in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270760/passing-a-string-by-reference-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java pass-by-reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who told you that "primitive values are pass-by-value and object reference are pass-by-reference". This is wrong.

In Java, everything is pass-by-value.

Now, objects are not manipulated directly but through references. Multiple references can point to the same object but these references are copied like any other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

References in Java are passed *by value*. So if you reassign the first argument in `TesingPrimitivRefernce.generateString` to something else, it is the *copy* of the `sample1` reference that is changed (you weren't trying to modify the argument using some... modifiers, were you? :)).

So, before the modification:

- sample1 `->` dog
- s `->` dog

After the modification:

- sample1 `->` dog
- s `->` dogdd (and this String object is lost once the method exits).

In the ArrayList case, you were modifying the underlying list, so the originally referenced object was modified.

Comment: what is reference copying technique?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created. At the moment you  pass a string to a method a copy of this string is created. All further changes in this method modify this copy, not the string itself.