# How does String works as Object in Java

Tags: java, string, reference

I am quite confused with how Object works in Java since I run into this problem.

Let's say I have a function called checkDateValue (code looks like this)

```
private boolean checkDateValue(Date d1, String msg) {
    if (d1 == null) {
        msg = "d1 is null!";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the place I call this function:

```
String msg = null;
Date d1 = null;
if (!checkDateValue(d1, msg)) {
    system.println(msg); //msg is still null..... 
                         //what I need is the message generated in the function
}
```

As far as I know, if I put a customized Object 
(e.g.

```
myObj { private String msg;}
```

) 
into a function, and we change the value of msg inside the function, when we get out of the function, the change of msg is kept. However, I think String is also considered as an Object in java. Why the change is not kept?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a String by Reference in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270760/passing-a-string-by-reference-in-java)

Comment: @delnan: I think you are right.. I have the same question as in that post.....

Comment: Thanks you for all you guys' help~!!! I think I got a clear idea now. I admit my keyword search skill is pretty bad......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String is special](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html), is [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and is diffrent from normal Object.
Java's [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is designed to be in between a primitive and a class.

[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is passed by value, but unfortunately every change on String make new value, so your old reference has old value.

I think this is good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270782/516167

Comment: Anyone can create an immutable class. String is special in some regards (e.g. there are literals), but not in this case. It's just another immutable class, and a reference type like every other class. And as I said before, mutability has no effect on what OP describes.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't have `"out"` function arguments; they are copies of references.
Even though you change `msg` in the function, it does not affect the caller's variable.

Answer (score 0):

`msg = "d1 is null!";` and `msg=null` are two different String objects. [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)s are immutable in Java.The reference is passed by value, i.e., a copy of the reference is passed.  and since a `String` is immutable object , the assignment inside the method creates a new `String` object that the copy of the reference now points to. The original reference still points to the null `String`. Your method call is same as :

```
Object obj = null; // obj points to nowhere
foo(obj); // passed the reference values to method argument
void foo(Object o)
{
   o = new Object( );  // o points to new Object, but obj still points to nowhere
}
```

Comment: Mutability has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @delnan - If `String` were mutable, then OP could pass in an empty string (instead of `null`) and have the method fill in a non-empty value as appropriate.

Comment: @delnan - Really? Can you think of any consequences if it were mutable ?

Comment: Yes, *of course* then one could mutate the object, but assignment works the same either way. It's my knee-jerk reaction because I keep seeing people explaining "you see, immutable objects work differently ..." and the original answer read a lot like that.

Comment: To be more specific, if inside the method the code was something of this sort `msg += "d1 is null!";` and if `String` were indeed mutable, then do you think Op would have got the o/p what he is getting in this case !

Comment: The way `+=` is currently defined, no it wouldn't, it would just be `msg = msg + "d1 is null";` ;-) An overloaded (yeah, not happening) `operator+=` or a mutating method would work though. And my point was exactly that - you'd need to perform a different operation, as assignment can never do what OP expects, regardless of mutability.

Comment: *"you see, immutable objects work differently ..."* , No you misinterpreted the answers , since `msg = "d1 is null!";` creates a new String object in this case , it was relevant to mention it while answering. If it were a `StringBuilder` object and you would have done `append()` to it , then both the references outside the method and method parameter would have been refering to the same object!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you cannot pass back a value to calling code by assigning to a method parameter. You are right that you can alter the internal structure of any parameter and that change will be seen in the calling code. However, assigning to a parameter is not the same thing as altering the internal structure. Also, a `String` is *immutable*—once created, its internal structure cannot be altered.

A common trick to do what you what is to use an array argument:

```
private boolean checkDateValue(Date d1, String[] msg) {
    if (d1 == null) {
        msg[0] = "d1 is null!";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
String[] msg = new String[1];
Date d1 = null;
if (!checkDateValue(d1, msg)) {
    system.println(msg[0]);
}
```

Comment: By "trick" you mean ugly hack that you should avoid like the plague.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - Not really. That "trick" is used in the core Java libraries. What's plague-like about it?

Comment: There's a difference between passing an array to retrieve a number of values, and passing a singleton array just to emulate pass-by-reference.

Comment: @delnan - Um, what's the difference? (And by "singleton array" I assume you mean an array of length 1, not an array that is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).)

Comment: One is the established pattern used in a number of libraries (Java and otherwise) and is perfectly natural, the other is a ugly hack (both implementation-wise and w.r.t the interface) to semantics that are usually neither useful not desirable. Or less literally, I'm saying you can't cite those uses of arrays-as-parameters to defend this "trick", as they use them for very different purposes. (And yes, I'm using singleton in the mathematical sense, i.e. containing a single element.)

Comment: @TedHopp The Java library is full of shocking code. I don't think it does it that often either, particular not in deliberately public APIs. It's a dirty hack.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the fact that

> Java passes objects as references passed by value.

You **can't** change the reference argument to point to something else. You **can** change the object state.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/1651233)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!checkDateValue(d1, msg)) 

{
    system.println(msg); 
}
```

when you call `checkDateValue` method a reference `String msg = null;
Date d1 = null;` to the method
is passed which is pass by value. When method gets executed then 
`msg` variable in `checkDateValue` will get referenced to "d1 is null!"
Here, `msg` variable in call remains same