# Java class file from PL/SQL procedure

Tags: java, oracle

I have a following PL/SQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getDogInfo
(Dog_ID IN NUMBER, Dog_name OUT VARCHAR) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT Dog_name INTO Name
  FROM Dog_family
  WHERE ID = Dog_ID;
END;
```

I need to make a java class file that does the same. I've been trying like this:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Procedure {

  public static void getDogInfo (int Dog_ID, String Dog_name)
    throws SQLException
    { String sql =
      "SELECT Dog_name INTO Name FROM Dog_family WHERE ID = Dog_ID";
    try { Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
      PreparedStatement apstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      apstmt.setInt(1, Dog_ID);
      apstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
      ResultSet rset = apstmt.executeQuery();
      rset.close();
      apstmt.close(); //Connection close
      }
    catch (SQLException e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me get this working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should read about JDBC (and Java in general too).

The query should be :

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Dog_family 
WHERE ID = ?
```

(assuming `Name` is the column name you are selecting from the table - it wasn't clear whether `Name` or `Dog_name` was the column name).

Then after you execute the query and get a result set :

```
String name = null;

if (rset.next()) {
  name = rset.getInt (1);
}
...
return name;
```

Finally, your function should return a String. You can't pass the String as a parameter and update its value. String is immutable in Java.

One more thing - the line `apstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);` is not needed. `registerOutParameter` is only used with `CallableStatement`, which is a statement you use to execute a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Have alook at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) showing you how to correctly use PreparedStatements.

You will find that the parameter should be `?` not `Dog_ID`

Try

```
SELECT Name FROM Dog_family WHERE ID = ?
```

It will also show you how to iterate through your resultSet

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do not tell us what the problem is, but I see several issue right away:

1. Your select statement should not have an INTO clause. That is a PL/SQL construct. You need to
   return the result of the query back as a result set.
2. Your input parameter, Dog_ID will not be used, because you have not
       named the parameter correctly in the SQL statement.
3. Java string parameters cannot be updated within the method, which I
   am assuming that is what you are attempting.  You either need to
   return a string value from the method, or use a StringBuilder
   reference, or some other container to pass in.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270760/passing-a-string-by-reference-in-java)
   There is no "out" parameter to register.  Read up on result sets [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/navigate-result-sets.htm)

So, change your SQL statement to something like this(since you are using a positional parameter as opposed to a named parameter):

```
"SELECT Dog_name FROM Dog_family WHERE ID = ?"
```