# The value of a variable does not get updated when I pass that to a method to do so?

Tags: java, variables, static, scope, program-entry-point

```
package com.mkyong.test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String something = "";
        callSomething(something);

        System.out.println(something);
    }

    private static String callSomething(String something) {
        something = "Hello Wrold !";
        return something;
    }
}
```

Comment: change callSomething(something); to something=callSomething(something);

Comment: another relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270760/passing-a-string-by-reference-in-java

Comment: String objects are immutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in the method, you are changing the reference of the local variable something.

Change your method call to:

```
something = callSomething(something);
```